# Iterating over TypedDict's keys

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, typeddict

Here's an example:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class Foo(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: int

foo = Foo(a='2', b=4)

for key in foo:
    print(foo[key])
```

I get

```
main.py:10: note: Revealed type is 'Any'
main.py:10: error: TypedDict key must be a string literal; expected one of ('a', 'b')
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I find this surprising - isn't it known that `key` is one of `foo`'s keys, and hence that `foo[key]` should be valid?

---

Playground URL: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=8972284897f25314f9c790eab4cb8548

Comment: Not strictly related, but in case you didn't know, you can do `for key, value in foo.items()` which entirely bypasses the issue. Though it of course doesn't address the limitation of mypy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's known issue which was discussed [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6262). If you want it to work now, just try # type: ignore which should overwritten the warning.

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Foo(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: int

foo = Foo(a='2', b=4)

for key in foo:
    print(foo[key]) # type: ignore
```

playground URL:https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=85e30e0187088219797a283c31d7ec7c